# How to embed youtube video on iOS 7

Tags: ios, youtube, ios7

I had this code on my app which works perfectly on iOS 6.

```
     - (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString 
{
       NSString *embedHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                  <html><head>\
                  <style type=\"text/css\">\
                  body {\
                  background-color: transparent;\
                  color: blue;\
                  }\
                  </style>\
                  </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                  <iframe height=\"140\" width=\"325\"      src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\"></iframe>\
                  </body></html>",urlString];
[VideoView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
}
```

In iOS 7 the VideoView shows the iframe, but when I tap the play button, it appears to load a new view to watch video but in a second it close itself. Why does this happen, and how to tweak it to work in iOS 7 too?

### **Update**

Finally apple release a stabil iOS firmware. iOS 7.0.3 fixed the issues :)

Comment: Others seem to have similar problems without solution :(. I noticed that in iOS7 Web App it takes three presses of play button in order to work, but at least it works.

Comment: But in my case, it won't work until seven presses, and no one (except dev) would try to press the button seven times. lol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this exact same issue where we tap the play button, it then appeared to load up the view full screen but then immediately dismissed itself.

This happened in an app which supports both iPad and iPhone.  In the iPad version the video was being displayed from a popover.  When the popover was dismissed the audio would still be playing.  To resolve this issue we added some code to viewWillDisappear to kill the video.

On the iPhone the behavior is different because it isn't in a popover.  However, we discovered that as the video is being launched it was firing viewWillDisappear also.  This was killing the video playback on the iPhone as soon as it was launched.

Long story short... you might want to check viewWillDisappear and make sure you aren't doing anything there that shuts the video down.

Answer (score 0):

It now works correctly with iOS 7.0.3.